# ASP.NET MVC 5 Return JSON Dynamic Object

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, json

I am retrieving a valid JSON string from a web service. I am then using Newtonsoft.Json to deserialize into a dynamic object and returning that to the client via an AJAX call.

However all that's being return is empty arrays which is very strange.

The only way I am able to return the JSON object is by sending it as a Content result with application/json. Ex:

```
return Content(beers, "application/json");
```

What's going on here? The above solution is "fine" however I don't want to return the entire JSON object, only the list of beers. Below is a simple example solution illustrating the issue.

http://andrewherrick.com/spike/beerjsondynamic.zip

Also I like beer if you can't tell :)